# Cross compiler error: reference 'm_memoryManager' cannot be decalred 'mutable' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling, xalan

I am compiling for Arm11 and use xalanc. I get a bunch of these:

```
In file included from /xx/include/xalanc/DOMSupport/DOMServices.hpp:39:0, 
from /xx/include/xalanc/XPath/XObject.hpp:39:43,
from xy/MYxpath.cpp:7:
/...xx/include/xalanc/PlatformSupport/XSLException.hpp:199:29: error : reference 'm_memoryManager' cannot be decalred 'mutable' [-fpermissive]
make: *** [MyPath/MYxpath.arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-gcc.Release.32.0] Error 1
```

Any idea?

EDIT_ Using gcc 4.7

Comment: Well, references are immutable.

Comment: Does this mean it's a bug in the xalanc sources?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [a bug/configuration issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANC-703). You need to modify `Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp` to workaround it.